# AWS-CDK Type "(cls: Runtime) -> Runtime" cannot be assigned to type "Runtime"

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I get this flycheck error pointing to the `runtime=_lambda..` variable:

`Argument of type "(cls: Runtime) -> Runtime" cannot be assigned to parameter "runtime" of type "Runtime" in function "__init__"   Type "(cls: Runtime) -> Runtime" cannot be assigned to type "Runtime"`

```py
# create lambda function
# executed as root
function = _lambda.Function(self,
                            "lambda_function",
                            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
                            handler="lambda_handler.main",
                            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset("./lambda"),
                            environment={
                                'EC2_INSTANCE_ID':
                                instance.instance_id,
                                'S3_OUTPUT':
                                output_s3.s3_url_for_object(),
                                'S3_INPUT':
                                input_s3.s3_url_for_object()
                            })
```

It's a rather cosmetic IDE issue, the code itself works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a bug in `jsii`, the library CDK uses to transpile TypeScript (the language in which CDK is written) to Python.

Here is [the PR that fixed it](https://github.com/aws/jsii/pull/3694). The fix was released in [1.64.0](https://github.com/aws/jsii/releases/tag/v1.64.0)

If you are using a version before 1.64.0, you can use casting to suppress the error:

```
import typing

...

function = lambda_.Function(
    self,
    "function",
    ...
    runtime=typing.cast(lambda_.Runtime, lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7)
)
```

Or just append `# type: ignore` to the end of the line to disable type checking on that particular line.

Comment: The CDK appears to be using jsii 1.84.0 as of CDK version 2.85.0. Since the version of jsii with the fix is in that release of the CDK, I would expect that this would no longer be flagged as a type error, but PyCharm 2023.1.3 professional edition still flags it.

Comment: @Gillfish I'm guessing that's due to some specifics around how PyCharm's checker works. I would open an issue in the jsii repo